# Filter unique objects from array list which has same property values '0'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array with objects which includes score values. I need to create a unique array of objects based on immediate same type values.

Note: If any object has immediate next same type values from previous object date as start date then it will make one unique array list.

Array :

```
[  
  { "score_value": 1, "category": "A" "date": "2023-01-01T00:00:00" },                   
  { "score_value": 2, "category": "A" "date": "2023-02-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 3, "category": "A" "date": "2023-03-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-04-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-05-01T00:00:00" },  
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-06-01T00:00:00" }
  { "score_value": 4, "category": "A" "date": "2023-07-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 5, "category": "A" "date": "2023-08-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 6, "category": "A" "date": "2023-09-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-10-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-11-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2023-12-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 0, "category": "A" "date": "2024-01-01T00:00:00" },
  { "score_value": 7, "category": "A" "date": "2024-02-01T00:00:00" }
]
```

Filter previous date where the 0 values started and its end with what date.

I expected below Output:

```
[{
  fromDate: "2023-03-01T00:00:00",
  toDate: "2023-07-01T00:00:00"
}, {
  fromDate: "2023-09-01T00:00:00",
  toDate: "2024-02-01T00:00:00"
}]
```

Comment: What effort have you made to try and solve this? Please show your code so that we can help you to debug it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array::reduce()` and check the next item with the current index plus `1`:

```js
const arr = [

{"score_value":1,"category":"A","date":"2023-01-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":2,"category":"A","date":"2023-02-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":3,"category":"A","date":"2023-03-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-04-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-05-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-06-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":4,"category":"A","date":"2023-07-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":5,"category":"A","date":"2023-08-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":6,"category":"A","date":"2023-09-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-10-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-11-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-12-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2024-01-01T00:00:00"}

];

const result = arr.reduce((range => (r, {score_value, date}, idx, arr) => {
  // if the next score is 0 - create new range
  if(score_value && !arr[idx + 1]?.score_value){
    r.push(range = {fromDate: date});
  // if the next score is not null or end of the array and we have a started range - close the range
  } else if ((!score_value && arr[idx + 1]?.score_value) || (idx === arr.length - 1 && range)){
    range.toDate = date;
    range = null;
  }
  return r;
})(), []);

console.log(result);
```

With destructuring of the next item:

```js
const arr = [

{"score_value":1,"category":"A","date":"2023-01-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":2,"category":"A","date":"2023-02-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":3,"category":"A","date":"2023-03-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-04-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-05-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-06-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":4,"category":"A","date":"2023-07-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":5,"category":"A","date":"2023-08-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":6,"category":"A","date":"2023-09-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-10-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-11-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2023-12-01T00:00:00"},{"score_value":0,"category":"A","date":"2024-01-01T00:00:00"}

];

const result = arr.reduce((range => (r, {score_value: curr, date}, idx, arr, {[idx + 1]: {score_value: next} = {}} = arr) => {
  if(curr && !next){
    r.push(range = {fromDate: date});
  } else if ((!curr && next) || (idx === arr.length - 1 && range)){
    range.toDate = date;
    range = null;
  }
  return r;
})(), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. But else condition it throws expression error.

Comment: Ok sure I will remember formatting next time.Thank you.